# Fat Free Framework (F3): custom 404 page (and others errors)

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

How I can handle my 404 custom page (and possibly other errors)?

I just tried in routing part to add

```
GET /@codes /WebController->error
```

Where my Class WebController handles error, and for 404 i solved (partially). In effect it works for

```
http://mydomain.ext/itdoesntexists
```

but if i recall a

```
http://mydomain.ext/sub/maybe_another_sub/and_so_on/doesnt_exist
```

My route (of course) doesn't work.

Btw, with that route in every case it doesn't push 404 header (just a maniac-vision of things, i'm thinking to Google looking for a resources and it doesn't receive a "pure" 404).

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't have to define a route for this. F3 will automatically generate a 404 status code for any non-defined route.

If you want to define a custom error page, you need to set the ONERROR variable.

Here's a quick example:

```
$f3->route('GET /','App->home');
$f3->set('ONERROR',function($f3){
  echo \Template::instance()->render('error.html');
});
$f3->run();
```

with error.html defined as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>{{@ERROR.text}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{@ERROR.text}}</h1>
  <p>Error code: {{@ERROR.code}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if you call any non-defined route like /foo, the template error.html will be rendered with a 404 status code.

NB: this works for other error codes. Other error codes are triggered by F3 or your application with the command `$f3->error($status)`, $status being any valid HTTP status code (404, 500, 403, etc...)

Comment: Is there a way to route the onerror call to a controller method?

Comment: Sure: `$f3->set('ONERROR','Controller->method');`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.