# How do I display a custom 401 page in Fat-Free Framework?

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, fat-free-framework

I'm new to F3 and I've just implemented a form-based login system (using the Auth plugin). It works, but my not-logged-in check looks like this:

```
if (!$f3->get('SESSION.user')) $f3->reroute('/login');
```

The example I was referring to, did this, which seems more correct:

```
if (!$f3->get('SESSION.user')) $f3->error(401);
```

However, this `401` error shows a simple error page. I want it to send back the login form (which is at `/login`) along with an error saying "You must be logged in" and I want this response to be a `401` instead of a `403` or `200`.

Am I right in expecting this behaviour or is a `401` only valid for HTTP Basic Auth and not custom form-based auth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the error response with the [ONERROR](http://fatfreeframework.com/framework-variables#AbouttheF3ErrorHandler) hook.

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
$f3->ONERROR=function($f3) {
  if ($f3->get('ERROR.code')==401) {
    // custom behaviour on 401
    echo \Template::instance()->render('error-401.htm');
  } else
    // default behaviour otherwise
    return FALSE;
};
```

```
<!-- error-401.htm -->
<h1>This page requires authorization</h1>
<a href="/login?path={{ @PATH }}">Click here to sign in</a>
```

Comment: Yup, I did the exact same thing soon after posting the question and reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763414/fat-free-framework-f3-custom-404-page-and-others-errors?rq=1